# Set extent of view in OpenLayers 3

Tags: javascript, geojson, openlayers-3

I've just started having a look at OpenLayers 3 and am attempting to zoom to a single feature whose extent is to be a geoJSON object sent by the server (which will change at each refresh, so I can't hard code the zoom/central point). I would like this to happen preferably as soon as the page loads, but I'm struggling to get it to work.

I keep getting an error saying "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function" at the line where I try to read the geometry from a geoJSON object, and I'm not really sure how to fix it. The geoJSON string seems fine (i've also tried parsing it before passing it to readGeometry but that gave the same results).

If there's an easier/faster way to do this than how I am currently, i'd be interested to hear it too!
Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
var feature = new ol.Feature({
});

var view = new ol.View({
  center: [0, 0],
  zoom: 1
});


var client = new XMLHttpRequest();
client.open('GET', 'http://localhost:3000/extent');
client.send();
client.onreadystatechange=function(){
    if (client.readyState==4 && client.status==200){
        var geomstring = client.responseText;
        console.log(geomstring)
        var geojson = new ol.format.GeoJSON();
        var geom = geojson.readGeometry(geomstring);
        var size = (map.getSize());
        feature.setGeometry(geom);
        view.fitGeometry(
        geom,
        size,
        {
            padding: [170, 50, 30, 150],
            constrainResolution: false
        });
    }
}

var map = new ol.Map({
  layers: [raster, vector, feature],
  target: 'map',
  });
```

Comment: Can you post an example of the GeoJSON? You probably have to use `readFeature()` instead of `readGeometry()`, but that depends on what your web service returns.

Comment: {"st_asgeojson":"{\"type\":\"Polygon\",\"coordinates\":[[[-2416.91312435933,6700304.87650272],[-2416.91312435933,6700339.02584392],[-2255.97853651961,6700339.02584392],[-2255.97853651961,6700304.87650272],[-2416.91312435933,6700304.87650272]]]}"}

It does seem that the GeoJSON bit isn't working properly as the object seems to be empty when I log it to the console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading the geometry should work like this:

```
var geojson = new ol.format.GeoJSON();    
var json = {"st_asgeojson":"{\"type\":\"Polygon\",\"coordinates\":[[[-2416.91312435933,6700304.87650272],[-2416.91312435933,6700339.02584392],[-2255.97853651961,6700339.02584392],[-2255.97853651961,6700304.87650272],[-2416.91312435933,6700304.87650272]]]}"};
var geom = geojson.readGeometry(json['st_asgeojson']);
console.log(geom.getArea());
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I'd not twigged that it was a dictionary itself. Finally got it sorted:

    var geojson = new ol.format.GeoJSON();
    var json = JSON.parse(client.responseText);
    var geom = geojson.readGeometry(json['st_asgeojson']);
    var feature = new ol.Feature({
    });
    feature.setGeometry(geom);
    console.log(feature.getGeometry());
    extent.getSource().addFeature(feature);